# How to check when BigQuery query result returns zero records?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jobs

I have a client API in python which executes BigQuery job to trigger a query and write query result into respective BigQuery table. How to determine whether that query result returns zero records at any execution or not?

Python code:

```
def main(request):

    query = "select * from `myproject.mydataset.mytable`"
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    dest_dataset = client.dataset(destination_dataset, destination_project)
    dest_table = dest_dataset.table(destination_table)
    job_config.destination = dest_table
    job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED'
    job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'
    job = client.query(query, location='US', job_config=job_config)
    job.result()
```

I want If query result is having none record then it should print some message for me. Can anybody suggest how to get this done.

Answer (score 11):

[`QueryJob.result()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html?highlight=job%20result#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.result) returns a [`RowIterator`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator), which has a property called `total_rows`.

So, something like:

```py
result = job.result()
if result.total_rows == 0:
  print('no results')
```

- Documentation: [`RowIterator.total_rows`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator.total_rows)

---

Updated per [@Dom Zippilli's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220373/how-to-check-when-bigquery-query-result-returns-zero-records/58221794#comment102916075_58221794): . `total_rows` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Does it check resultant pages of source BigQuery table or destination BigQuery table where we are trying to write the data from source BQ table ? For example, my destination table already have some rows in it, and when I run above python script it will trigger the query to fetch data from source BQ table, but as a result it doesn't have any rows to write into destination table. Then which page count does your code considers(from source or dest BQ table)?

Comment: In my source BQ table I just have schema with no records, When using your line of code it is not executing If statement and creating destination table having same schema like source BQ table but with no records.

code which I am trying:
job.result()
result = job.result()
if result.pages == 0:
    print('no results')
else:
    print('some results are there')

Comment: what is the value of `result.pages` you are seeing, then?

Comment: If I do print(result.pages), It gives me "<generator object Iterator._page_iter at 0x000001976653ED58>" as output.

Comment: That iterator also has a [total rows property](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator.total_rows), which I think has misleading text in the docs. It refers to the number of rows in the result set, not the table being queried.